# Setar conteúdo de ImageView por meio de uma URI

Tags: android

Galera, estou tentando setar a imagem no ImageView da minha segunda Activity  através de uma URI que vem da primeira Activity mas até agora sem sucesso. O que pode estar errado?

```
File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

      String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"; 

      uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem));
```

@Edit

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);  
    startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURAR_IMAGEM);

 public void chamarTela(){
    Bundle dados = new Bundle();
    dados.putString("foto",uri.getPath().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TelaPraVerImagem.class);
    intent.putExtras(dados);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_pra_ver_imagem);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
    //imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
   // TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mensagem);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null){
        if(intent.getExtras() != null){
           Bundle dados = intent.getExtras();
           String  imgpath = dados.getString("foto");
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgpath);
           imageView.setImageURI(uri);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usar o **setImageUri()** não é a melhor maneira de setar imagem na sua UI, pode causar alguma falhas na latência na hora de dar o decode.

Ao invés disso, use o **setImageBitmap()**:

```
//Transforme sua URI em um Bitmap
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath()); 
imgView.setImageBitmap(myImg);
```

**@Edit**

Suspeito que o **getPath()** não esta retornando o path verdadeiro de sua imagem. Quando você acessa o path via **getPath()**, o retorno seria mais ou menos esse:

### .\file\image.jpg

PS: a classe URI implementa um Parcelable, ou seja, você pode extrair ela diretamente da sua intent.

Tente isso:

```
public void chamarTela(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TelaPraVerImagem.class);
    intent.putExtra("foto", uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}

...
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null){
        if(intent.getExtras() != null){
            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("foto");
            Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath().getAbsolutePath()); 
            imgView.setImageBitmap(myImg);
        }
    }
```

**@Edit2**

[Seguindo a documentação do Google](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), acredito que realmente você esteja colocando o path errado na hora de criar a imagem

Segue o código com alguns comentarios:

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Criando o nome de uma imagem. Você pode seguir o padrão Brasil aqui
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    //Um detalhe aqui, não é garantido que o device tenha um getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), 
    //É importante você fazer esta validação
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefixo */
        ".jpg",         /* sufixo */
        storageDir      /* diretorio */
    );

    // Esse é o path que você vai utilizar na resposta da sua Intent
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void chamarTela() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Criando um File que aponta onde sua foto deve ir
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ...
        }
        // Continua apenas se sua foto foi salva de verdade
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private void setPic() {
    // Pegando as dimensões de sua View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Pegando as dimensões do Bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determinando o quanto que deve diminuir de tamanho/qualidade
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Garantindo que o Bitmap fique boa dentro de uma View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Alterei, mas mesmo assim a imagem não aparece.

Comment: Qual a origem da URI? Link da web ou interno?

Comment: @Wakim É interno uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem));

Comment: Poderia incluir uma amostra? É que do schema da imagem, pode ter um tratamento diferente.

Comment: @Wakim Ok, amostra adicionada!

Comment: Resposta editada!

Comment: @sicachester segui seu procedimento mas mesmo assim não aparece a imagem, mas setei um text view para saber o path que esta vindo que é este /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1410183174.jpg

Comment: @user8398 o problema é que você está dando um `Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem))`, mas esta linha de código não cria a imagem propriamente dita. Aonde você está escrevendo/salvando essa imagem?

Comment: @sicachester então, esse Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem)) é para referenciar a foto que foi tirada com a chamada da Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: @Renan você está passando a imagem com o caminho na hora de chamar a `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`? Inclui a chamada completa por favor

Comment: @sicachester Editei, dê uma olhada!

Comment: @Renan editei a resposta. Acredito que agora você consiga fazer o que você quer. Coloquei nos comentários um detalhe sobre o `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` que você deve ficar atento

Comment: @sicachester acho q estou entendendo errado, pois minha duvida nesse código é o seguinte, em que parte você esta enviando essa imagem para a segunda Activity que possui somente um ImageView? No primeiro código que eu postei a imagem esta sendo salva sim, pois eu emito um broadcast para realmente adicionar a imagem na galeria.